# How to display password repository of user on Solaris 11?

Tags: authentication, solaris, password, repository, aix

Is there a convenient way to find out which password repository (ldap or files) user is using for atuhentication on Solaris 11.2?

I myself have AIX administration background and there is **lsuser** command that displays all info about user including password repository. But i can't find such thing on Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

The file /etc/nsswitch.conf lists the sources for (among others) passwd:

```
#
# /etc/nsswitch.files:
#
# An example file that could be copied over to /etc/nsswitch.conf; it
# does not use any naming service.
#
# "hosts:" and "services:" in this file are used only if the
# /etc/netconfig file has a "-" for nametoaddr_libs of "inet" transports.

passwd:     files
group:      files
hosts:      files dns [NOTFOUND=return]
[truncated]
```